# celery autodiscover_tasks not working for ValueError: Empty module name

Tags: celery

I tried to reuse the autodiscover_tasks function in my app without using django, but it always throw ValueError: Empty module name when doing autodiscover_tasks in my celery.py

```
consumer/
        /__init__.py
        /celeryapp/
                  /__init__.py
                  /celery.py
                  /celeryconfig.py
        /test1/
              /__init__.py
              /tasks.py
```

I execute the celery(/usr/bin/celery) command in consumer directory

```
$cd /path/to/consumer
$celery worker -A celeryapp.celery -l debug
```

celeryapp/celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('celeryapp.celeryconfig')
app.autodiscover_tasks(['test1'])
```

test1/tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celeryapp.celery import app

@app.task
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

Error Message:

$ celery worker -A celeryapp.celery -l debug

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 307, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 761, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 693, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 179, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 212, in run
    state_db=self.node_format(state_db, hostname), **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 128, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 116, in import_default_modules
    signals.import_modules.send(sender=self.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 166, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/amqp/utils.py", line 42, in __call__
    self.set_error_state(exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/amqp/utils.py", line 39, in __call__
    **dict(self.kwargs, **kwargs) if self.kwargs else kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 329, in _autodiscover_tasks
    self.loader.autodiscover_tasks(packages, related_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 251, in autodiscover_tasks
    related_name) if mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 272, in autodiscover_tasks
    return [find_related_module(pkg, related_name) for pkg in packages]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 290, in find_related_module
    pkg_path = importlib.import_module(package).__path__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ValueError: Empty module name
```

Comment: I just found that the strange thing is when I specify "force=True" in autodiscover_tasks(), then it works fine. By checking celery codes, it seems this parameter will cause self._autodiscover_tasks() called immediately, by default it just postpond until some signal received, so I assume this parameter is optimized for using with django only to implement lazy module loading, but still I have no idea why it failed in signal handler.

Comment: This is what helped me

Answer (score 0):

Before the autodiscover_tasks call,you should:
1,os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","dj_gaomu.settings")
2,django.setup()